# How to deploy nuxt3 application on hosting via FTP

Tags: nuxtjs3

Hello my dear developers. Help me plz with that question.
I have Laravel api application and nuxt 3 as a frontend application.
With Laravel i had no problems with deploing but with nuxt...
So as documention says i need to run nxp nuxi generate command. But its creates fully static site, and its working but api calls not really works.
I want to deploy on my server that has linux and other required thinks also installed (..etc node)
I want to deploy it via ftp. That some pages are static but some pages are requests data from api when we update the page.
How can i do it plz.

I tryed npx nuxi generate.Also with ssr false in nuxt config file.
I tryed npm run build. But its says just error.

Comment: Mind sharing the error?

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks for a reply.
So my steps.
1. npm run build. Now i got .output/server and .output/public. 
2. via ftp i load .output/public to the server.
3. im going to my site. and its says
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

if i use npx nuxi generate. and put public to my server. It works but fetch data not working when i refresh the page

Comment: Nginx looks at .output/public folder

Comment: If you want to use your Nuxt app as SSR, you need to `build` and then follow this: https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/node

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reviewing my question and comments to it.
So i used npx nuxi generate and also i putted ssr false in nuxtconfig
The i pushed .output/public to my server via ftp.
And everything works great.

In future i want to add some pages in nuxtconfig to preload them. So they will be fully static. Hope i can do it. (i`m still learning...)

The problem that confused me, is that when i did it first time, its loaded with fetched data, and when i tryed to change data. I could see any errors. And when i made my database fully emty it still showed data. But when i tryed to do it now, it works. I don`t really understood why.  Hope maybe it will help someone. Becouse its not really enought info in interner. Or i`m just a bad googler xD
Peace to everyone

Comment: So you're using your Nuxt app as SPA-only?

Comment: MM, it will be a store. So i dont really think it will be Single Page Application. I`m still very new to Nuxt3. Previously i worked only with Laravel (laravel blades) and clean js.
Now i want to do in that way so nuxt3 just full frontend and laravel api

Comment: I`m confused how it will works with seo. Main pages will be using fetch. But i still want that seo will render the page. So it should be preloaded but with fetch working... Can`t understand really how it works for now... And there is not enough information right now =(

Comment: You should probably stick to SSG and host it on Netlify if you're beginning. Also, SPA-only (as you have set it as of right now) will not be the best for a store.

Comment: But how to deal, if admin changes some properties on admin side. But App is already build and it doesnt fetches new data

Comment: An SSG Nuxt app, still have the SPA part after the hydration step. So, it's not blocking: you can still do dynamic stuff there. Meanwhile, if you thing is behind a login initially, an SPA could be a good approach too (SEO is not available behind a login).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I`ll learn more about SSG and how to deal with dynamic contents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem quite new, I recommend that you stick to:

- vanilla Vue3 app
- hosting on Netlify

When you'll be more comfortable with those, then you could proceed hosting a Nuxt3 app on your own VPS.